# Plotting different linear functions

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to optimize a linear function by using a gradient descent method.
At the end of my algorithm, I end up with a vector of a coefficients and b coefficients of the same dimensions which are different from a and b that were calculated by my algorithm.

For each combination of a and b, I would like to plot a linear function         y = a*x + b knowing that I generated x and y.

The own is to have all the representations of the intermediate linear functions that were calculated through the algorithm. At the end I want to add the linear regression obtained by lm() to demonstrate how well the method can optimize the a and b coefficients.

It should look like this: [linear functions obtained thanks to the different a and b coefficient calculated with the algorithm method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2jdx.jpg)

This is the code that I wrote for plotting the different linear functions:

```
#a and b obtained with algorithm


h = function (a,b,x)  a * x + b 
data = matrix(c(a,b,x), ncol = 3, nrow = 358) 
# 358 is the length of the vectors

i = 1
for (i in length(a)){
plot(h(a[i,1],x[i,3],b[i,2]))
i = i+1
}
```

One of the problem that annoys me is that I am not sure that I can superimpose the linear functions without using the plot and the points functions. 
The second one is that I am not sure that I can plot a linear function if I give the a and b coefficient ?

Would you have a better idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The function `abline` will add straight lines to a plot. It can also be used to plot a line straight from a regression.

You don't give any sample data (next time, include sample data in your question!), but it would look something like this:

```
set.seed(47)
x = runif(50) - 0.5
y = 4 * x + 1 + rnorm(50)

a_values = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10)
b_values = seq(0, 4, length.out = 10)

plot(x, y)
for (i in seq_along(a_values)) {
  abline(a = a_values[i], b = b_values[i], col = "dodgerblue2")
}

abline(lm(y ~ x), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it is going to help me a lot !